# PDF getting partially downloaded with status 200 and logs in ZUUL Gateway showing SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, http, netflix-zuul

We are trying to download multiple PDFs from spring boot micro-service application and display the content of PDFs in browser.The flow is , client hits to zuul gateway and gateway calls to spring boot application. Spring boot application responsible to give PDFs.

Case 1 : 
When ten multiple PDFs sized of 150KB,500KB,10MB,10MB,10MB,40MB,40MB,40MB,5MB,5MB then few PDFs are completely downloaded where as bigger size file three 40MB files are partially downloaded upto 19MB(sometimes size differ) with status code 200.

Case 2: 
The same 40MB file alone getting completely downloaded.

When partially PDF getting downloaded , logs in zuul gateways give SocketException: Connection reuse.

Already tried:

1. Increase the server timeout to 30 min in Gateway , Spring boot application and browser side still no luck. Within 5 minutes all the PDFs getting downloaded along with those partial PDF
2. Tried to add an extra zuul error filter , which is responsible to send 401/500 incase of SocketException occurs but client side still 200 status is showing in case of partially downloaded PDFs

public class CustomErrorFilter extends ZuulFilter{

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomErrorFilter.class);
protected static final String SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN = "sendErrorFilter.ran";

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    // return RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getThrowable() != null;
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object run() {

    /*try {*/

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        Throwable throwable = ctx.getThrowable();

        if (throwable != null) {

             //ctx.setResponseBody("Zuul exception:" + throwable.getMessage() + " cause: " +
            // throwable.getCause()); // just for development purposes
            // ctx.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
             //ctx.setResponseStatusCode(401);
             //ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
             //ctx.setResponseBody("401");
             //ctx.set(SEND_ERROR_FILTER_RAN);

            //throw new RuntimeException("there is a problem in downloading file");
             //return null;
            ZuulException zuulException = new ZuulException("User message", 500, "Error Details message");
            throw new ZuulRuntimeException(zuulException);
        }
    /* } */
        /*catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception filtering in custom error filter", ex);
            throw ex;
        }*/

        return null;
}

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return ERROR_TYPE;
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return SEND_ERROR_FILTER_ORDER+Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

}

Please suggest why this filter is not running.

For partial PDF downloaded , we want different status code except 200.

Comment: I know this sounds unrelated, but we had a similar problem with an SSRS server and PDFs -- the download would start and then timeout.  The resolution was (and I'm still skeptical about this, but it works) to use https instead of http.  The explanation had to do with Acrobat and certificates.  I know, it sounds crazy to me too, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Is there any possibilities that in zuul gateway side , I can set different status code except 200 by using zuul error filter or zuul controller when partial download is happening. Any idea ?